# Error 1001 in my Windows Service app setup project

Tags: windows-services, setup-deployment

I'm trying to install my Windows Service app using Visual Studio 2008 Setup and Deployment project. I have created a user account that has "Run as a Service" right and have set the ServiceProcessInstaller.Account to System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User and also the username and password to the user that I have created previously.

```
spInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
spInstaller.Username = "USER NAME";
spInstaller.Password = "PASSWORD";

sInstaller.ServiceName = "SERVICE NAME";
sInstaller.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
```

But during the setup process, I get the following error:

**Error: 1001. The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified**

Any ideas why I get this error and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you specifying a Domain for your UserName. I.e. if you machine is called FASTCAR have you tried

```
spInstaller.UserName = "FASTCAR\\UserName";
```

Comment: do you know how to avoid the popup asking for admin user and pass ?

Comment: Good tip. works for me and I was just trying to enter it in the box at time of install. I hope the panda is no longer sad.